# JTable jQuery integrate with Spring MVC 3 issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-jtable

I have an issue with `JTable` integration to Spring MVC

******** *JSP code* *****************

```
<link href="http://www.jtable.org/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://www.jtable.org/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://www.jtable.org/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.jtable.org/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.jtable.org/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

//setup the jtable that will display the results
$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Table of people',

        actions: {
            listAction: '/admin/getalltherole',
            createAction: '/admin/addRole',
            updateAction: '/admin/updateRole',
            deleteAction: '/admin/deleteRole'
        },
        fields: {
         custId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            name: {
                title: 'Full Name',
                width: '30%'
            },
            birthYear: {
                title: 'Birth Year',
                width: '15%'
            },
            employer: {
                title: 'Employer',
                width: '25%'
            },
            infoAsOfDate: {
                title: 'As Of Date',
                width: '15%'
            },
            disabled: {
                title: 'Status',
                width: '15%'
            }
        }
    });
    $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');
});

</script>

<div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: 600px;"></div>
```

******* *Spring controller*  ******************

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/getalltherole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonJtableResponse getalltherole(){
    JsonJtableResponse jstr = new JsonJtableResponse();
    jstr.setResult("OK");
    List<Role> roleList = testService.getAllRoles();
    jstr.setRecords(roleList);
    return jstr;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonJtableResponse insert(@ModelAttribute Role role, BindingResult result) {
    JsonJtableResponse jsonJtableResponse = new JsonJtableResponse();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult("ERROR");
    }
    try {
        Role newRole = testService.saveRole(role);
        //jsonJtableResponse.setRole(newRole);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult(e.getMessage());
    }
    return jsonJtableResponse;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/updateRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonJtableResponse update(@ModelAttribute Role role, BindingResult result) {
    JsonJtableResponse jsonJtableResponse = new JsonJtableResponse();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult("Error");
        return jsonJtableResponse;
    }
    try {
        testService.updateRole(role);
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult("OK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult(e.getMessage());          
    }
    return jsonJtableResponse;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/deleteRole", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonJtableResponse delete(@RequestParam Integer custId) {
    JsonJtableResponse jsonJtableResponse = new JsonJtableResponse();
    try {
        testService.deleteRole(custId);
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult("OK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jsonJtableResponse.setResult(e.getMessage());            
    }
    return jsonJtableResponse;
}


JSON response object

public class JsonJtableResponse {

    private String Result;

    private List<Role> Records;

    public String getResult() {
        return Result;
    }

    public void setResult(String Result) {
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    public List<Role> getRecords() {
        return Records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<Role> Records) {
        this.Records = Records;
    }   
}
```

********** obtained JSON response *******************

```
    {
   "result":"OK",
   "records":[
      {
         "custId":"1",
         "name":"aaa",
         "birthYear":"1982",
         "employer":"xxx",
         "infoAsOfDate":"20130110",
         "disabled":"true"
      },
      {
         "custId":"2",
         "name":"bbb",
         "birthYear":"1982",
         "employer":"xxx",
         "infoAsOfDate":"20130111",
         "disabled":"true"
      },
      {
         "custId":"3",
         "name":"ccc",
         "birthYear":"1982",
         "employer":"xxx",
         "infoAsOfDate":"20130108",
         "disabled":"false"
      },
      {
         "custId":"4",
         "name":"ddd",
         "birthYear":"1981",
         "employer":"xxx",
         "infoAsOfDate":"20130107",
         "disabled":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

ISSUE ***************************

I can obtain the given JSON response using firebug console.

but when page loads it throws this error on firebug console, even though JSON data properly gets loaded,

```
   "NO Data available"
```

message is displayed on the data table.

and there is an error on the console as well.

```
   "TypeError: this._$errorDialogDiv.html(message).dialog is not a function"
```

As I have searched, this error is typically due to jquery UI libs not properly being added.

when I change - listAction: `'/admin/getalltherole'` to some non existent URL

```
 "An error occured while communicating to the server." is displayed in a dialog box.
```

**jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js** includes all the required jquery UI libs and I tried adding all the libs individually as well, without any luck.

any suggessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Jackson library, maven dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can add json property annotation to your fields in the class so that the json output is rendered as you expect. You may write a generic class (JsonJtableResponse in your question) as given below:

```
public class JTableJSONResponse<T> {
    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private String result;

    @JsonProperty("Records")
    private List<T> records;

    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("TotalRecordCount")
    private int totalRecordCount;

    public JTableJSONResponse(String result, List<T> records, int totalRecordCount) {
        super();
        this.result = result;
        this.records = records;
        this.totalRecordCount = totalRecordCount;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, your controller may say

```
List<Role> roleList = roleService.getAllRoles();
return new JTableJSONResponse<Role>("OK",roleList,roleList.size());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is case-sensitive. So it would not be able to match "result" with "Result". I had faced the same issue with my app as well.

So please ensure that your JSON response returns Result and Records in the correct case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that JSON response which was required for JTable to be case sensitive.

NOT

```
 {
 "result":"OK",
 "records":[
  .......
  ]}
```

but

```
   {
   "Result":"OK",
   "Records":[
   .......
   ]}
```

Comment: Hi,i have done proper capitalization in my code for JSON. Yet I am facing the same issue. "an error occurred while communicating to the server"

This alert shows up in my application when i redirect from one tab to another while 1st tab is not loaded fully.

Do you have any idea why am I facing this and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the type of error you are facing you are missing some js file to be imported .

have you added the `json2.js` which is an external dependency for jtable

https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/tree/master/lib/external

it is mentioned in the following example for jtable and it is missing in your code

http://www.jtable.org/Tutorials/UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods#CreatePage

also check with the help of firebug that all the js file are loaded or not.

Comment: hi Meherzad,

all the js files are properly loaded. I have added json2.js as well, but no luck with that still same error..