# Pass selected jquery jtable rows to constroller in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using Jquery Jtable to display a grid. I want to pass the selected rows from the grid to my spring MVC controller.
I want to know if I can pass the selected rows to the controller.

Following is my Jquery Jtable code

```
          j('#claimsInfoTableId').jtable({

        paging : true, //Enable paging
        pageSize : 10, //Set page size (default: 10)   
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true,
        actions : {

                 listAction: '${baseURL}/claimTrackingHistoryListPaginationDataTablesAjaxCall.html', 

        },

         fields: {


                claimId : {
                            title : 'Claim Id',
                            width : '20%',
                            key : true,
                            list : true,
                            edit : true,
                            create : false
                        },
                claimPool : {
                            title : 'Claim Pool',
                            width : '20%',  
                            list : true,
                            edit : true,
                            create : false

                        },

         }


    });
    j('#claimsInfoTableId').jtable('load');
```

Comment: Does the generated table have `data-record-key=""` property for each `<tr>`?

Comment: yes. The generated table have data-record-key="" property for each <tr>

Comment: Are you trying to create/update/delete a claim record? What information is your controller expecting? Is this record going to be written to some database through JPA or similar? See if the following post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313322/jtable-jquery-integrate-with-spring-mvc-3-issue?rq=1

Comment: I have an Update button at the bottom. When user clicks this button all the rows should be passed to the controller to update in the database. User may or may not modify the rows but still each row should be passed to the controller.